# Make_shared - own implementation

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to make my own implementation of `shared_ptr`. I have problems with `make_shared`. The main feature of `std::make_shared` that it allocates counter block and object in continuous block of memory. How I can do the same?

I tried do something like that:

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr
{
private:
    class _ref_cntr
    {
    private:
        long counter;

    public:
        _ref_cntr() :
            counter(1)
        {
        }

        void inc()
        {
            ++counter;
        }

        void dec()
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                throw std::logic_error("already zero");
            }

            --counter;
        }

        long use_count() const
        {
            return counter;
        }
    };

    template<class _T>
    struct _object_and_block
    {
        _T object;
        _ref_cntr cntr_block;

        template<class ... Args>
        _object_and_block(Args && ...args) :
            object(args...)
        {
        }
    };

    T* _obj_ptr;
    _ref_cntr* _ref_counter;

    void _check_delete_ptr()
    {
        if (_obj_ptr == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }

        _ref_counter->dec();

        if (_ref_counter->use_count() == 0)
        {
            _delete_ptr();
        }

        _obj_ptr = nullptr;
        _ref_counter = nullptr;
    }

    void _delete_ptr()
    {
        delete _ref_counter;
        delete _obj_ptr;
    }

    template<class _T, class ... Args>
    friend shared_ptr<_T> make_shared(Args && ... args);

public:
    shared_ptr() :
        _obj_ptr(nullptr),
        _ref_counter(nullptr)
    {
    }

    template<class _T>
    explicit shared_ptr(_T* ptr)
    {
        _ref_counter = new counter_block();
        _obj_ptr = ptr;
    }

    template<class _T>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_T> & other)
    {
        *this = other;
    }

    template<class _T>
    shared_ptr<T> & operator=(const shared_ptr<_T> & other)
    {
        _obj_ptr = other._obj_ptr;
        _ref_counter = other._ref_counter;

        _ref_counter->inc();

        return *this;
    }

    ~shared_ptr()
    {
        _check_delete_ptr();
    }

};

template<class T, class ... Args>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args && ... args)
{
    shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    auto tmp_object = new shared_ptr<T>::_object_and_block<T>(args...);
    ptr._obj_ptr = &tmp_object->object;
    ptr._ref_counter = &tmp_object->cntr_block;

    return ptr;
}
```

But when I delete object and counter block, the invalid heap block exception occurs.

Comment: Two mandatory pieces of code that surround shared pointer management are (a) the reference counting algorithm, and (b) the actual *delete*, both of which you've chosen *not* to include in this post. We're not mind readers. Post a [**complete MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the actual problem. The statement "when I delete object and counter block..." suggests you're deleting *two* things that were never *directly* allocated (in fact the only direct allocation, `tmp_object`, is never retained at all).

Comment: Your implementation is missing some key features. If you add them, the solution might simply appear out of the existing code. What's missing: type-erasure for the deleter, storing a pointer unrelated to the managed object (and maybe more, like thread-safe ref counting, weak ref counting, ..) `shared_ptr` is complicated, and it took long to develop the current form.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

N.B. `_T` is a [reserved name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/981959) and you must not use it for names of your own types/variables/parameters etc.

The problem is here:

```
void _delete_ptr()
{
    delete _ref_counter;
    delete _obj_ptr;
}
```

This is wrong for the `make_shared` case because you didn't allocate two separate objects.

The approach taken for `make_shared` in Boost's and GCC's `shared_ptr` is to use a new derived type of control block, which includes the reference counts in the base class and adds storage space for the managed object in the derived type. If you make `_ref_cntr` responsible for deleting the object via a virtual function then the derived type can override that virtual function to do something different (e.g. just use an explicit destructor call to destroy the object without freeing the storage).

If you give `_ref_cntr` a virtual destructor then `delete _ref_counter` will correctly destroy the derived type, so it should become something like:

```
void _delete_ptr()
{
    _ref_counter->dispose();
    delete _ref_counter;
}
```

Although if you don't plan to add `weak_ptr` support then there is no need to separate the destruction of the managed object and the control block, you can just have the control block's destructor do both:

```
void _delete_ptr()
{
    delete _ref_counter;
}
```

Your current design fails to support an important property of `shared_ptr`, which is that the  `template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* ptr)` constructor must remember the original type of `ptr` and call delete on that, not on `_obj_ptr` (which has been converted to `T*`). See the [note](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#pointer_constructor) in the docs for the corresponding constructor of `boost::shared_ptr`.  To make that work the `_ref_cntr` needs to use type-erasure to store the original pointer, separate from the `_obj_ptr` in the `shared_ptr` object, so that `_ref_cntr::dispose()` can delete the correct value. That change in the design is also needed to support the [aliasing constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#aliasing_constructor).

```
class _ref_cntr
{
private:
    long counter;

public:
    _ref_cntr() :
        counter(1)
    {
    }

    virtual ~_ref_cntr() { dispose(); }

    void inc()
    {
        ++counter;
    }

    void dec()
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("already zero");
        }

        --counter;
    }

    long use_count() const
    {
        return counter;
    }

    virtual void dispose() = 0;
};

template<class Y>
struct _ptr_and_block : _ref_cntr
{
    Y* _ptr;
    explicit _ptr_and_block(Y* p) : _ptr(p) { }
    virtual void dispose() { delete _ptr; }
};

template<class Y>
struct _object_and_block : _ref_cntr
{
    Y object;

    template<class ... Args>
    _object_and_block(Args && ...args) :
        object(args...)
    {
    }

    virtual void dispose() { /* no-op */ }
};
```

With this design, `make_shared` becomes:

```
template<class T, class ... Args>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args && ... args)
{
    shared_ptr<T> ptr;
    auto tmp_object = new shared_ptr<T>::_object_and_block<T>(args...);
    ptr._obj_ptr = &tmp_object->object;
    ptr._ref_counter = tmp_object;

    return ptr;
}
```

So `_ref_counter` points to the allocated control block and when you do `delete _ref_counter` that means you you have a correctly-matched `new`/`delete` pair that allocates and deallocates the same object, instead of creating one object with `new` then trying to `delete` two different objects.

To add `weak_ptr` support you need to add a second count to the control block, and move the call to `dispose()` out of the destructor, so it is called when the first count goes to zero (e.g. in `dec()`) and only call the destructor when the second count goes to zero. Then to do all that in a thread-safe way adds a lot of subtle complexity that would take much longer to explain than this answer.

Also, this part of your implementation is wrong and leaks memory:

```
void _check_delete_ptr()
{
    if (_obj_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
```

It's possible to constructor a `shared_ptr` with a null pointer, e.g. `shared_ptr<int>((int*)nullptr)`, in which case the constructor will allocate a control block, but because `_obj_ptr` is null you will never delete the control block.

Comment: Wow! It's amazing. But I have a question about weak_ptr support. When there are no `shared_ptr`s I should delete _obj_ptr. But when there are still some `weak_ptr`s, I still should maintain `_ref_cntr` object, right? But when this `_ref_cntr` is  `_object_and_block`, I can't delete _obj_ptr without deleting _ref_cntr.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In GCC's implementation my equivalent of `_object_and_block` doesn't have a member of type `Y`, instead it has a buffer of raw memory of type `std::aligned_storage<Y>::type`, and it then creates the `Y` in that buffer using placement new, and  `dispose()` does `reinterpret_cast<Y*>(&buffer)->~Y()` to destroy it. This allows the lifetime of the `Y` object to end sooner than the lifetime of the `_object_and_block` that contains it.

Comment: So, even in GCC, memory for object releases only when the last `weak_ptr` dies?

Comment: Yes, that's true for all `make_shared` implementations I know of.

Comment: I've got another issue about custom deleter. What should I do if `_ref_cntr` is `_object_and_block` and custom deleter passed? Deleter gets pointer to object as argument, but when it's a field in `_object_and_block` it can cause problems.

Comment: `_object_and_block` is only used when `make_shared` gets called, and that doesn't support a custom deleter. For custom deleters you need another derived type, like `_ptr_and_deleter_and_block<Y, D>` which stores `Y*` and `D` (and similar for custom allocators).

Comment: As usual, Jonathan, this answer absolutely rocks. I wish I could uptick it a few more times. Really nice work.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks :) Implementing `shared_ptr` is subtle and complicated, but doesn't require any actual magic, so I'm happy to be able to share how it works